Anylogic : Hold block which condition on an event timeout
Hi I have a problem with hold block, I want to use hold block on certain condition which will unblock when a event "night" occur, but I can't set up the condition by using true or false on condition on block, how do I integrate the hold block with my event? i'm really new to either anylogic or java.
All the code or step will be helpful. Thank you.

Can you explain more what you expect, ex the sample code, or more about hold block look like

it more like how a ship cross a river which cannot be done at night so what i do is i set a event called Day which occur for 12 hours and add block hold with condition for each agent and add blocking condition with Day(true); which get some error the method Day(boolean) is undefined for the type Main. how do i fix this, is it something wrong ? my goal is to make the hold block unblock when the event called day occur

In your event, either call myHold.block() or.unblock() (depending on what your event actually does)
If you want, you can use 2 events: one to block and one to unblock

Thankyou for the answer, i have used .unblock on an event, but unfortunately only 2 ship pass through and other is stuck eventhough the event is not active, how do i fix this, i think my event setup has something to do about it. I want to set up condition about day and night, an what i set is the day (with cycling event occurance at 6, and reoccurance every 12) and the action is to unblock, however it only unblock for the first 2 ships, is it something wrong with my event setup? i want to make a variation of hours of a day
